# Read.csv gives dataset with wrong numbers

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

I have a comma seperated dataset of around 26,800 rows. When doing read.csv, R creates a dataframe and everything seems to be fine. However, R gives me wrong numbers when performing statistical analysis. I checked my numbers with the official numbers of the website from which I downloaded the dataset and they deviate in some cases a lot. I thought that the removal of categories, such as "Don't know" or "Refused to answer", could be the reason for wrong share percentages. However, it gives me also wrong numbers when using `count()` and including all categories. I checked also my codes for values and factor levels several times, but the numbers are already wrong before I manipulate the dataset.

I don't know what else I could check. I could imagine that the way my program handles the CSV file could result in misrepresentation of the data. The CSV is with 22.8 MB quite large.

Here the header and the first five rows:

```
id,country,psu,splita,splitb,wave,q1,a1,q13,wt,stratum,sample,mode,Q1001,Q1001GCC,Q1002,Q100,Q2061A,Q2061B,Q101,Q101A,Q102,Q108_1,Q108_2,Q108_3,Q108_4,Q109AGCC_1,Q109AGCC_2,Q104,Q104A,Q104A_1,Q104A_2,Q104A_3,Q104A_4,Q104A_5,Q104A_6,Q104A_7,Q104A_8,Q104A_98,Q104A_99,Q104B_KSA,Q104B_UAE,Q104B_QA,Q104B_BA,Q104B_KU,Q104B_OM,Q104B_EG,Q104B_JO,Q104B_LEB,Q104B_MO,Q104B_AL,Q104B_TUN,Q104B_TUR,Q104B_US,Q104B_CAN,Q104B_UK,Q104B_EEU,Q104B_FR,Q104B_GER,Q104B_ESP,Q104B_IT,Q104B_WEUOTHER,Q104B_SSA,Q104B_OTHER,Q104B_DK,Q104B_REF,Q104B_WEU,Q104C,Q105,Q103,Q201A_1,Q201A_2,Q201A_3,Q201A_5,Q201A_41,Q201A_42,Q201A_7,Q201B_6,Q201B_13,Q201B_20,Q201B_31,Q201B_12,Q201C_37,Q201C_38,Q201C_39,Q201C_32,Q201C_40,Q513,Q204A_1,Q204A_2,Q204_2,Q204_3,Q204_11,Q204_20,Q204_22,Q204B_13,Q204B_15,Q204C_13,Q204C_15,Q205_1,Q205_4,Q205_4LEB,Q205_6,Q205_7,Q214,Q211D,Q209B,Q210,Q211,Q211A,Q211B,Q211C,Q213B,Q213A_1,Q213A_2,Q213A_3,Q209,Q216,Q218_2,Q218_5,Q218_6,Q501,Q501A,Q266,Q502_1,Q502_2,Q502_4,Q265,Q263,Q404,Q301A,Q301B,Q303A,Q302,Q503A,Q505A,Q301C,Q601A,Q516A,Q515A2,Q511,Q512,Q514,Q514A,Q516_1,Q516_2,Q516_3,Q516_4,Q423_1,Q423_2,Q423_3,Q409,Q424,Q412A3,Q412A4,Q412A6,Q412A7,Q412A8,Q412A9,Q412A10,Q412A14,Q412A98,Q412A99,Q421,Q521_1,Q521_4,Q521_5,Q521A_3,Q521A_4,Q852,Q853A,Q853B,Q854,Q855A,Q855B,Q851_E1,Q851_E2,Q851A,Q851B,Q851C,Q851D_1,Q851D_2,Q851D_3,Q851D_4,Q851D_5,Q851D_6,Q851D_7,Q851D_98,Q851D_99,Q860A,Q860B,Q860C,Q860D,Q1012,Q1012A,Q609,Q609A,Q610_8,Q610_5A,Q610_5B,Q610_6A,Q610_6B,Q610_9,Q601_1,Q601_3,Q601_4,Q601_7,Q601_9,Q601_9A,Q601_14,Q601_18,Q602_1,Q602_2,Q602_3,Q602_4A,Q602_4B,Q604A_1,Q604A_3,Q604B_1,Q604B_3,Q606_1,Q606_2,Q606_3,Q606_4,Q606_8,Q607_2,Q607_6,Q607_7,Q605,Q605A_1,Q605A_2,Q605A_3,Q605A_4,Q605B,Q700A_1,Q700A_2,Q700A_8,Q700A_9,Q700A_4,Q700A_3,Q700A_13,Q700A_12,Q701C_1,Q701C_2,Q701C_3,Q701C_4,Q701C_5,Q701C_6,Q701F_1,Q701F_2,Q701F_3,Q701G_1,Q701G_2,Q701G_3,Q701G_4,Q701G_5,Q701H,Q703,Q705,Q706A,Q706B,Q707,Q707_1,Q707_2,Q707_3,Q707_4,Q707_5,Q707_6,Q707_7,Q707_8,Q725_1,Q725_2,Q725_3,Q709B,Q7141A,Q7141B,Q833,Q841,Q1003GCCA,Q1003,Q1020JO,Q1001A,Q1001B,Q1001C,Q1001D,Q1005,Q1006,Q1006A,Q1006C,Q1006C_GCC,Q1006C_GGC1,Q1006D,Q1006E,Q1006F_1,Q1006F,Q1006G,Q1010,Q1010C,Q1010B1,Q1010B2,Q1018,Q1018A,Q1018B,Q1018C,Q1018D,Q1018E,Q1018F,Q1014A,Q1015A_LEB,Q1015B_LEB,Q1015C_LEB,Q1015A_JO,Q1015B_JO,Q1015C_JO,Q1015A_PAL,Q1015B_PAL,Q1015C_PAL,Q1015A_MO,Q1015B_MO,Q1015C_MO,Q1015A_TUN,Q1015B_TUN,Q1015C_TUN,Q1015A_EG,Q1015B_EG,Q1015C_EG,Q1015A_SUD,Q1015B_SUD,Q1015C_SUD,Q1015_YEM,Q1015A_YEM,Q1015A_IR,Q1015B_IR,Q1015C_IR,Q1015A_AL,Q1015B_AL,Q1015C_AL,Q1015A_LI,Q1015B_LI,Q1015C_LI,Q1015A_KU,Q1015B_KU,Q1015C_KU,Q1016,Q1017,date
1,1,1,2,2,5,10009,10001,1,0.3544727765156059,1,1,1,33,NA,1,3,2,6,3,5,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,NA,3,NA,NA,NA,98,98,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,2,98,3,3,NA,3,4,3,3,2,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,4,NA,3,97,98,98,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,4,2,NA,2,1,99,3,3,3,2,2,2,NA,1,98,2,10003,3,2,3,2,3,6,3,NA,NA,98,2,98,2,2,98,98,1,2,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,98,4,4,98,2,2,98,3,NA,2,2,98,1,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,5,2,6,3,2,NA,3,NA,4,3,1,3,4,NA,98,2,1,2,3,3,3,NA,NA,NA,98,4,2,98,98,2,98,3,2,3,1,1,98,2,2,1,98,3,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,NA,2,NA,2,2,98,4,1,98,2,98,2,1,5,NA,3,2,1,98,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,98,2,4,NA,98,3,3,NA,6,NA,10016,15,3,1,2,1,2,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,4,1,2,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,4,2019-02-03
1,10,1,2,2,5,100001,NA,1,0.8228747696314179,2,1,1,56,NA,1,2,8,2,3,3,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,3,3,3,NA,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,3,2,2,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,NA,NA,NA,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,2,NA,3,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,NA,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,3,NA,4,2,1,NA,3,1,2,3,2,6,8,NA,1,3,3,3,1,2,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,6,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,NA,2,2,2,1,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,2,1,2,3,NA,NA,3,NA,3,NA,2,2,4,2,NA,2,2,3,3,2,1,NA,2,NA,NA,3,3,2,3,3,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,2,2,1,3,2,2,3,NA,3,NA,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,5,NA,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,4,3,2,NA,4,2,1,NA,4,NA,100001,56,3,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,4,NA,1,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,2,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,1,2018-10-03
1,13,1,2,3,5,130001,130001,1,0.8407776951789856,1,1,1,28,NA,1,2,2,8,3,5,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,4,2,3,4,3,4,4,4,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,4,3,4,4,0,3,4,4,4,4,4,NA,NA,NA,4,4,3,4,NA,4,4,1,2,4,1,4,4,NA,4,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,3,2,2,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,NA,3,3,2,0,2,2,2,3,3,0,10,NA,2,4,4,4,2,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,6,2,3,4,1,2,2,3,NA,3,2,3,2,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,5,2,4,2,3,NA,3,NA,2,3,4,4,3,NA,2,4,4,3,3,4,2,NA,NA,NA,2,2,3,3,3,2,1,3,4,2,3,2,2,4,3,1,1,3,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,NA,3,NA,3,3,2,3,2,1,2,1,2,2,3,NA,2,3,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,4,4,2,NA,1,2,2,NA,5,NA,130001,28,3,1,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,4,2018-10-22
1,15,1,1,3,5,150007,150001,1,1.4914801402683608,17,1,1,54,NA,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,1,3,2,1,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,4,3,4,4,NA,3,3,1,3,4,2,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,2,2,3,4,2,98,NA,2,3,NA,NA,2,2,NA,2,3,2,1,3,1,2,2,3,NA,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,3,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2,1,NA,98,1,150011,3,1,1,3,3,5,10,2,NA,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,NA,0,0,6,2,2,1,3,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,13,2,5,1,1,NA,2,NA,4,2,2,3,2,3,NA,2,2,3,5,3,3,NA,2,3,NA,NA,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,NA,NA,2,4,1,2,2,2,1,1,98,1,NA,3,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,98,1,3,4,NA,1,1,NA,6,NA,150001,54,1,2,2,1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,NA,2018-10-07
1,19,1,1,3,5,190001,190001,1,0.6597576880207578,1,1,1,53,NA,1,2,1,13,3,4,5,1,2,1,1,NA,NA,1,8,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,NA,3,3,3,3,4,3,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,3,3,3,99,3,4,NA,3,3,NA,NA,3,4,NA,2,2,98,2,98,98,NA,NA,4,NA,2,98,1,1,4,4,4,4,NA,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,2,NA,3,98,0,98,2,3,3,98,1,8,4,NA,3,4,3,3,2,1,3,1,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,4,4,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,98,1,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,1,13,2,6,2,2,NA,2,NA,4,3,1,1,4,3,NA,2,1,3,2,3,3,NA,1,2,NA,NA,2,3,2,98,4,98,1,4,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,98,3,98,1,1,2,98,98,1,98,1,1,NA,NA,98,4,1,98,2,98,2,2,98,1,NA,98,2,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,98,1,2,98,NA,98,4,NA,5,NA,190001,6,3,1,1,2,2,3,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,2,NA,4,1,1,2,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,NA,2018-09-21
1,10,1,2,2,5,100001,NA,1,0.8228747696314179,2,1,1,56,NA,1,2,8,2,3,3,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,3,3,3,NA,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,3,2,2,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,NA,NA,NA,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,2,NA,3,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,NA,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,3,NA,4,2,1,NA,3,1,2,3,2,6,8,NA,1,3,3,3,1,2,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,6,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,NA,2,2,2,1,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,2,1,2,3,NA,NA,3,NA,3,NA,2,2,4,2,NA,2,2,3,3,2,1,NA,2,NA,NA,3,3,2,3,3,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,2,2,1,3,2,2,3,NA,3,NA,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,5,NA,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,4,3,2,NA,4,2,1,NA,4,NA,100001,56,3,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,4,NA,1,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,2,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,1,2018-10-03
1,13,1,2,3,5,130001,130001,1,0.8407776951789856,1,1,1,28,NA,1,2,2,8,3,5,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,4,2,3,4,3,4,4,4,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,4,3,4,4,0,3,4,4,4,4,4,NA,NA,NA,4,4,3,4,NA,4,4,1,2,4,1,4,4,NA,4,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,3,2,2,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,NA,3,3,2,0,2,2,2,3,3,0,10,NA,2,4,4,4,2,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,6,2,3,4,1,2,2,3,NA,3,2,3,2,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,5,2,4,2,3,NA,3,NA,2,3,4,4,3,NA,2,4,4,3,3,4,2,NA,NA,NA,2,2,3,3,3,2,1,3,4,2,3,2,2,4,3,1,1,3,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,NA,3,NA,3,3,2,3,2,1,2,1,2,2,3,NA,2,3,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,4,4,2,NA,1,2,2,NA,5,NA,130001,28,3,1,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,4,2018-10-22
1,15,1,1,3,5,150007,150001,1,1.4914801402683608,17,1,1,54,NA,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,1,3,2,1,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,4,3,4,4,NA,3,3,1,3,4,2,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,2,2,3,4,2,98,NA,2,3,NA,NA,2,2,NA,2,3,2,1,3,1,2,2,3,NA,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,3,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2,1,NA,98,1,150011,3,1,1,3,3,5,10,2,NA,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,NA,0,0,6,2,2,1,3,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,13,2,5,1,1,NA,2,NA,4,2,2,3,2,3,NA,2,2,3,5,3,3,NA,2,3,NA,NA,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,NA,NA,2,4,1,2,2,2,1,1,98,1,NA,3,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,98,1,3,4,NA,1,1,NA,6,NA,150001,54,1,2,2,1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,NA,2018-10-07
```

Does anyone have an idea for what could have been the problem?

Comment: you can try other readers like `data.table::fread` or `readr::read_csv` and check. if the results stay the same you will know it is not the reading function which causes your troubles

Comment: Yes, the results stay the same. I checked the website's other dataformats as well and it still gives me the same results.

Comment: can u provide some lignes of the `csv` so we could reproduce the error

Comment: See updated post. I included just five rows as there are many columns.

Comment: Which numbers are wrong? I have tried it out, but cannot see any errors. Have you tried to explicitly set *sep* and *dec* in your call to *read.table*?

Comment: I mean if I perform `count()` on a column, it gives me different numbers for each category compared to the official numbers from the dataset provider.